# RSS feed from Yammer

Tags: rss, yammer

Can I get RSS feeds from yammer ? I do not want to use the yammer feed webpart but RSS viewer webpart or anything else where I can customize the look and feel.

Comment: did you try to use RSS feed webpart?

Comment: Yes. But there is no URl for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to solve you problem is create a Web Part that use the yammer APIs, like the following example:

```
var embedFeed = function ( network, prompt ) {
    yam.connect.embedFeed ( {
        container : '#embedded-group-feed',
        network : network,
        config : {
            header : false,
            promptText : prompt
        },
        feedType : 'open-graph'
    } );
};

var config = function ( network, prompt ) {
    var yammerConfigSettings = getYammerConfigValues ( );

    if ( network === '' )
        network = yammerConfigSettings [ 0 ] [ 0 ];

    yam.config ( { appId : yammerConfigSettings [ 0 ] [ 1 ] } );

    embedFeed ( network, prompt );
};
```

Today also is possible authenticate your users on yammer by sharepoint/adc: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457819(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457819%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Yammer has no RSS-feeds available for you. So that way is closed (all though it exists third party tools that claims they can give you an RSS feed for yammer, like https://zapier.com/zapbook/yammer/rss/3798/create-rss-feed-of-yammer-messages/).

I would encourage you to explore the Yammer API:s, that might be useful (like https://developer.yammer.com/connect/), but I have a vague memory of them not being supported with SharePoints authentication models, hopefully fixed by now!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version of SharePoint you are using, but I can suggest you the possibilities.

**Using RSS Feed Web part**

1. Obtain the relevant feed URL from Yammer site.
2. For example, Choosing the group feed type will display all Yammer conversations for a particular group. You’ll need to know the Yammer group ID. To find this information, sign into Yammer.com and navigate to the group. Now look at the URL address for the page you’re on. The group ID is a set of digits at the end of the URL. Look for, “…group&feedID=1111111”, where “1111111” is the group ID.
3. Add an RSS Feed Web part into your page and submit this external feed URL. External feed works even for SharePoint Online.

**Using Content Editor Webpart**

Use the below code

```
<script>
yam.connect.embedFeed(
{ container: '#embedded-feed'
, network: '' // update with your own
});
</script>
<div id="embedded-feed"></div>
```

1. Save the code above in a text file (e.g. yammer.txt), and upload it to a document library in SharePoint
2. Open the page on which you want to display your feed. Bring it into edit mode, and add a Content Editor Web Part. Edit the web part, and add the path to your file under Content Link and click OK
3. If you’ve signed in, the feed will load.

Comment: Could you please look into this question -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286507/yammer-authorization-error

Comment: You say "3.Add an RSS Feed Web part into your page and submit this external feed URL. External feed works even for SharePoint Online." but what do you mean by external URL? Do you mean the entire URL like https://www.yammer.com/xxx/#/threads/inGroup?type=in_group&feedId=xxx? This doesn't seem to be an RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

We tried the zappier route, but were underwhelmed.
We were able to use the yammer REST API. We created a O365 account and had that account subscribe to all groups we wanted in the feed. We were then able to use that account's oauth_token with the api calls. We still have to parse the results and only announcements get titles. We're only using Author, Date, Title, and Description.
We used the api https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json documented https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messagesjson

We had to structure the output into our "RSS" feed which is still something we are trying to refine.

You can get this user's oauth_token by logging them into your yammer site and then opening the dev tools in chrome. On the Application tab under cookies, if you look at the http(s)://www•yammer•com cookie you will find that user's oauth_token. Since we implemented this last year it's changed once and we just had to update our C# asp.net website with the new token.

This allowed us to pull the All Company feed along with specific groups.

Comment: I think we will end up using the parts from this format.
https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/annotated-rss20-dc.html
Title, Description, dc:creator, and pubDate. I think just added Yammer Post to the end of the titles will fix the post that don't have titles.